# Visual Studio XAML editor: expand/collapse disappeared

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

Suddenly all the expand/collapse icons in the code editor have disappeared (the little '+' and '-' icon):

[image]

How can I bring them back?

Comment: I have not been able to fix this issue, only the first Window, DockPanel and Scrollviewer elements have the expand/collapse buttons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

enable this option from Tools -> Option .... in your case goto XAML option instead of C#...you need to close and reopen file for get setting applied
[image]

Comment: Interesting ... the 'Advanced' option does not exist in Text Editor -> XAML. I think @Mitan solved it with the '*you need to close and reopen file*' addition